# UIBezierPath change width of a path's segment

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, uibezierpath

I'm trying to develop a drawing application, and I need to change the width of the path according to the speed of the hand.

I tried to use moveToPoint to start another subpath

```
myPath.moveToPoint(myPath.currentPoint)
myPath.lineWidth = myPath.lineWidth + 1
```

but it doesn't work, it changes the width of the entire path.

Do you know if there's a way to change only a subpath's width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible. All `UIBezierPath` properties (`lineWidth`, `flatness`, ...) apply to the entire path with all its subpaths.

To draw curves with different line widths you have to create multiple bezier paths.